# Where can I find SharedPRefs file on my MotoG device ? It is with KitKat BTW

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

Generally for SharedPRefs file the path is like : `data/data/com....application..package..name/shared_prefs/filename.xml`.

But when I tried to navigate through the same path on my MotoG device, I don't see anything like this after

`/data/..... :(`

Can you guys help me please....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your phone is not rooted. By default, only the application itself can access files in `/data/data/com.whatever`, so that casual users don't edit the files and break the app. To see these files, you need to root the device and use a file explorer tool that can use root (this is usually called a "root explorer" app or feature).

Comment: Thank You, how can I root my phone ?

Comment: That's a completely different question, depending on several factors usually. A good start would be reading our [rooting tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info) :)

Comment: Cool...started reading it now...Will take it up from here on...Again...Thanks :)